# Initializing search in vi before starting

Tags: vi, patterns

I use a small program I wrote that takes a regular expression pattern as parameter and searches 2000+ files. The files are in a directory hierarchy.

The pattern can be in multiple files and multiple times in any file. After finding the filenames and the lines on which the pattern occurs, the program calls `vi` with `+line` for the first line number and all the filenames it found.

It all works now, but at one time I tried to specify `+line` for each file ( `vi +2 x1 +5 x2`), but that gets the cursor on line 5 in `x1` and line 1 in `x2`, not what I wanted, so I discarded that idea.

The patterns are often complex and I don't want to type them twice, so I now sometimes use copy and paste to search the next line in `vi`. What would be great, is to setup the `vi` search history with the pattern, then I could use <kbd>/</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, without retyping or copy/paste, to find all of the patterns. I can then use `:n!` to go to next file and continue using the pattern.

It looks like the pattern is stored `.viminfo` in my directory. Can I just update that file, before starting `vi` or is there some library or commandline utility to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to patch the `~/.viminfo` file.

As you are using `vim` you can use the `+/pattern` commandline option to get the cursor on the line of the pattern. After that you can use <kbd>n</kbd> to get to the following occurrences (if not at the start of the line it will be the first otherwise the second occurrence).

The man page says that the cursor will be at the first occurrence of the pattern, but in my experience it is on the first character of the line with that pattern. From the `vim` `man` page:

```
+/{pat}     For  the  first  file the cursor will be positioned on the
            first occurrence of {pat}.  See ":help search-pattern" for
            the available search patterns.
```

Comment: Yes I am using `vim` as `vi`. Would I have a `viminfo` if I did not? I am going to try this, thanks.

Comment: You're right, not paying attention.

Comment: @user86872: I'm not sure whether you're asking this, but: the `+/pattern` option works in plain `vi` as well as `vim`.

Comment: @G-Man I thought it was a vim addition, but then I have not used plain vi for quite some time.

Comment: @G-man using vim